# Raise3D Wi-Fi Protocol

Tags: wi-fi, protocol

I am interesting in connecting my RepRap printer to ideaMaker using the same Wi-Fi protocol they use for their Raise3D printers.

[image: Raise3D Wi-Fi protocol]

I am sure I could emulate it using a Raspberry Pi if I knew the format of the protocol (I suspect it is pretty simple).

1. Is the protocol documented anywhere?
2. Is there open source for something that uses the protocol?
3. Has anyone that has a Raise3D printer looked at the packets it uses?  I suspect the protocol is just G-code in a wrapper.

Comment: 3) is not a suitable question for stackexchange.

Comment: Why isn't 3) acceptable?  what rule is it breaking?  There is nothing illegal about it?

Comment: It's not a question. It's a request. Your (entire) question reads as if you are trying to start a *discussion* on reverse-engineering the Raise3D protocol. This isn't a discussion board, and the Q&A format (with a single question followed by a set of answers) isn't the right place for the back-and-forth discussion that would inevitably be necessary for this reverse engineering. I guess the answer to your question will ultimately be "no, it's a proprietary protocol and nobody knows how it works" and I don't think we can/should go further than that on this site.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I modified the question  to remove reverse engineering request

Comment: If this is 3D printing related i guess it should stay here . Why idea maker ? why not  use something  like Octopi ?  Is it just for ease of use ?

Comment: Somewhat ironically, there *is* a [Reverse Engineering SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) in beta. It might be worth asking your edited out question there. I rather like this question, and it is something that I could get my teeth into. Have you made any progress since asking it?

Comment: @Greenoline.  This hasn't made it on my work list yet.  Using my printer stand-alone using the SD card seems to work well.  Robotics season is over for now so the printer is pretty idle anyway.  Also, I have a lot of other project ahead of this one.

Comment: What is the benefit of using this setup instead of Octopi?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list question of 3 related, but not well-defined questions.

Comment: @Trish I think the general question is clear an on-topic, can you make recommendations on how to improve it.

Comment: @markshancock The question is on topic, but it is 3 questions. Where is the documentation (on topic, stackable). Is there OS use of it (on topic, but not stackable because it is a list question). What are the packages in the Raise3D protocol? (on topic, stackable, probably also Reverseengineering.SE?).

Comment: @Trish The main question is "What is the Protocol"
The three listed questions are just alternate paths to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have found the first piece of this puzzle.
"The Raise3D printers listen on TCP port 31625 for remote control from ideaMaker."